# Working with in memory file

Tags: c++, c, caching, memory-management

As I understand, if we load any file once for reading then it remain in RAM as **per LRU algo** till does not get swapped by other file.

In my **C program**, I am loading **124MB** text file to reads it's content. Ideally once I execute it should be in RAM and next time when I execute the same program soon it should take it from RAM only.

But here time taken in both the cases are **15s** only, without any regards to how much time I execute the same program.

And as cache size is very limited like **3MB**, putting inside cache not possible.

What can be other alternative for this to fasten the program execution?

Update:

Code link :

http://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~sajib/cmput606/project/code/svm_classify.c - This file contains main() class and performs the classification job

http://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~sajib/cmput606/project/code/svm_common.c - This file contains fucntion which are used to read file and perform the classification

Comment: Don't run your program more than once. Maybe you could use a loop?

Comment: Which cache? And did you really use all the data in the first run you needed in the second, or did you skip it? Also, are you sure the first one was a cold run?

Comment: @KerrekSB: every time user input, which I have process is different. so could not put it in loop

Comment: @Deduplicator: Yeah, I have to use all data in first run as well in every run. Because it's SVMrank trained classification file, which is used to classify the input text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loading a 120MB file should take less than 1 second on a decent SSD. 2-3 seconds for a HDD.  I can assume you don't read the file in large chunks but read it in small increments using function from the standard library (e.g. `fscanf` or use `fstream`).

Try reading the file in large chunks (1-16MB) and do your processing on that buffer.

If there are a lot of I/O calls to read the file, you have a lot of overhead caused by switching back and forth from kernel to user mode and other processes asking for I/O.

**Edit:** 
 lots of calls to `fscanf` and `gets`. Try reading the whole file to a single buffer and work on that buffer. use the `read` (not `fread`) to read the file in one shot.

If the file is too big, split it to 1MB reads.

**Edit2**

In the function `read_model` replace `fscanf` with `sscanf` to work on a buffer.
Read all the model in one shot to a large buffer of the file size. File size can be found using `stat`.   Instead of using `fgets` iterate the buffer using `strtok`.     The latter can be used to replace new lines with NULL chars while iterating them.

If you don't know any of these functions, try googling `man funcname`. E.g. `man strktok`.

Comment: yeah, I am going through opensource code for 4 days. I have added the link. I really appreciate if you can just give look and give my any suggestion

Comment: thank you very much, I am going again and again through the code, I could not find and decide where and how to decide reading buffer size in chunk of 1-16mb. Though you have already given so much details, It would be great help if you please point me out that

Comment: See updated answer, if this doesn't improve significantly, then run a profiler and see where you code stalls. Might be unrelated to file reads.

Answer (score 3):

Once your file is read for the first time, under a normally configured OS it's very likely that the involved disk pages are effectively cached.

Assuming that this memory is not required for other processes, second reads will be way faster than the first one.

As a quick test, we generate a random file and calculate md5sum twice (example in Linux):

```
$ dd if=/dev/urandom of=/tmp/readtest count=124 bs=1M

$ echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches  # needs to be run as root

$ time md5sum /tmp/readtest 
f788abe8a8d120a87bb293e65e5d50ff  /tmp/readtest

real    0m5.706s
user    0m0.332s
sys 0m0.072s

$ time md5sum /tmp/readtest 
f788abe8a8d120a87bb293e65e5d50ff  /tmp/readtest

real    0m0.295s
user    0m0.268s
sys 0m0.024s
```

Observe the huge difference after dropping the cached pages.

There are reasons why you may not appreciate this:

- The file is actually already cached when you first read it (most likely)
- Caching is disabled for this disk or partition, or unsupported for the filesystem/device (very unlikely).

Comment: yeah thank a lot for these efforts. Even I tested your code. It's really functioning as you have described. In my case I even expect the similar behaviour but it is giving me pain for last 3-4 days

Comment: Here is the package that I am dealing with http://www.hlt.utdallas.edu/~altaf/cherrypicker.html and it is using http://svmlight.joachims.org/ svm classifier inside it. Once I download, there only one command to test it

Answer (score 1):

If you read the file as a whole, the file will be in RAM if your OS caches it. If, between two runs, cache pressure makes your OS (the Linux kernel as an example) throw away the loaded file, your file will read it from disk again.

However, your program has no control over whether the file comes from cache or not. The OS gives your program the file, whether from the disk or from the file cache is outside your control.

Some more information can be found in this little article: [Experiments and fun with the Linux disk cache](http://www.linuxatemyram.com/play.html)